# Local user not part of any usergroup; can't add it to any; account not listed

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, user-accounts

Removed a local user from the administrators group and am getting `error 1317` on `net` command, trying to add it to a user group.

User isn't listed in users gui (cp, settings), but is listed on `net user` command (with an empty usergroup entry).

User profile content in Explorer and Registry entries are intact.

Is there a way to recover the user account, restoring the profile settings (or copy them to a new account)?

**Update:**

This is what `net` command instructs you to do, in order to add a user to a (local)group:
`net localgroup <groupname> <username> /ADD`.
This repeatedly resulted in `net` issuing system error 1317 ("The specified account doesn't exist").

This is what solved the issue:
`net localgroup <groupname> <computername>\<username> /ADD` (NOTE: don't use quotes in groupname, otherwise account will be listed as part of group, but not functionally recognized as such).
"The command was concluded with success". Account is now available and working.

Credit goes to: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/user-accounts-missing-windows

Comment: What tool did you use to remove the group?

Comment: Command line `net` command.

Comment: User the GUI through Administrator Tools > Computer Manger

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can't see any relatable entry there.

Comment: Using `wmic useraccount get domain,name,sid` I can see the account I'm trying to recover listed as SID *-1001.

Comment: Windows pro?  `lusrmgr.msc` from a run or command window

Comment: Home. Can't use the snap-in.

Comment: Please post a full answer with your solution, if you have found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a local user to a local group through `net` command, you *need* to include `computername`, as well as `username`, as below (this isn't stated, or even implied, in `net` command help):

```
net localgroup <groupname> <computername>\<username> /ADD
```

Merely including `username` will result in system error 1317 ("The specified account doesn't exist").

From: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/user-accounts-missing-windows (NOTE: don't use quotes in `groupname`, unlike in the link, otherwise account will be listed as part of group, but not functionally recognized as such).